# Parse JSON in R in an equivalent way as parsing JSON in Snowflake

Tags: r, json

I use R and Snowflake often. Parsing JSON in Snowflake is a piece of cake. For example, given a table with 3 columns - user, grouping, json - I can easily flatten the JSON and grab text from specific elements, as follows:

```
with json_data as (SELECT 'a' as user,  'z' as grouping, '{  \"123\": {    \"info\": {      \"text\": \"Hello\",    },    \"id\": \"123\"  },  \"456\": {    \"info\": {      \"text\": \"Good bye\",    },    \"id\": \"456\"  }}' as json)

select user
, grouping
, flat.key
, flat.value:info:text::string

from json_data
, lateral flatten(try_parse_json(json)) as flat
```

with the result as
[image]

I can create the same data in R but am not sure how to use `jsonlite` or a similar package to essentially create the same table:

```
data <- data.frame(user="A", 
grouping="Z", 
json='{
  "123": {
    "info": {
      "text": "Hello",
    },
    "id": "123"
  },
  "456": {
    "info": {
      "text": "Good bye",
    },
    "id": "456"
  }
}')
```

How would you accomplish this?

Comment: Try `library(jsonlite); read_json()`. And then `flatten()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to be able to parse the json and process it. Since the json is of different dimensions than the dataset you have its a bit wonk. Here's a solution that might be able to help.

We create a helper function that will process the json into a data.frame for you. Then we use that in `mutate()` to create a new column that processes the json. Next we unnest it (widen and lengthen the data), and select only the necessary columns. The names aren't identical, but it get's the point across.

Note that for parsing json RcppSimdJson is going to be much faster than jsonlite.

```r
data <- data.frame(user="A", 
                   grouping="Z", 
                   json=
'{
  "123": {
    "info": {
      "text": "Hello"
    },
    "id": "123"
  },
  "456": {
    "info": {
      "text": "Good bye"
    },
    "id": "456"
  }
}')

library(dplyr)
library(RcppSimdJson)

clean_json <- function(json) {
  tibble::enframe(fparse(json)) |> 
    tidyr::hoist(value, id = "id", info = c("info", "text"))
}

data |> 
  mutate(parsed = list(clean_json(json))) |> 
  tidyr::unnest(parsed) |> 
  select(user, grouping, id, info)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   user  grouping id    info    
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>   
#> 1 A     Z        123   Hello   
#> 2 A     Z        456   Good bye
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I could not install RcppSimdJson - kept getting errors, but I learned through this about the `hoist` function, so this code works:

  data %>%
    group_by(user, grouping) %>%
    mutate(parsed = list(fromJSON(json))) %>%
    unnest(parsed) %>%
    hoist(parsed, id="id", info = c("info", "text"))